# Delete line that matches specific string/value

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I have a flat file called "Master_Data" with below lines:(Considering Customer_Key is primary key)

```
Customer_Key,Customer_ID,Location
"1","1001","Washington D.C"
"2","1002","Los Angeles"
"3","1003","New York"
```

I receive similar file structure called "Daily_Data". I need to append the lines to "Master_Data" file in case it's new line.Update / Delete the existing line. For instance i received the "Daily_Data" file as below:

```
Customer_Key,Customer_ID,Location
"3","1003","Austin"
"4","1004","San Jose"
```

Then my code should produce/modify the "Master_Data" file as below:

```
Customer_Key,Customer_ID,Location
"1","1001","Washington D.C"
"2","1002","Los Angeles"
"3","1003","Austin"
"4","1004","San Jose"
```

I have tried this so far

```
sed -n '2,$p' /users/files/Daily_Data.csv >> /users/files/Master_Data.csv
```

But this just copies the data from Daily_Data and append to Master_Data as below:

```
Customer_Key,Customer_ID,Location
"1","1001","Washington D.C"
"2","1002","Los Angeles"
"3","1003","New York"
"3","1003","Austin"
"4","1004","San Jose"
```

What should i use/try to eliminate the line `"3","1003","New York"` in best possible way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk, you can do this:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0; next} $1 in a{$0=a[$1]; delete a[$1]} 1;
END{for (i in a) print a[i]}' Daily_Data Master_Data

Customer_Key,Customer_ID,Location
"1","1001","Washington D.C"
"2","1002","Los Angeles"
"3","1003","Austin"
"4","1004","San Jose"
```

**Reference:** [Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, 'NR == FNR {print; id[$1]; next} !($1 in id)' Daily_Data Master_Data
```

```
Customer_Key,Customer_ID,Location
"3","1003","Austin"
"4","1004","San Jose"
"1","1001","Washington D.C"
"2","1002","Los Angeles"
```

To sort that, you can do

```
awk ... | { read -r header; echo "$header"; sort -t'"' -k2,2n; }
```

To save that back to Master_Data, do one of:

```
awk ... > tmp && mv tmp Master_Data
awk ... | sponge Master_Data         # using `sponge` from `moreutils` package
```